# python : How to make fahr2cels and cels2fahr function

Tags: python

1.
 I want to make a function like this format

```
def fahr2cels(fahr) : 
    # code that converts fhar to cels
    cels = (5/9)*(fahr-32)
    return cels
```

2. And this is what I want to do

```
temperatures = [62, 67, 73, 83, 87, 96, 100, 100, 97, 88, 84, 70]
for t in temperatures : 
    fahr2cels(t)
```

why only one value comes out even letter t is defined as a list?

Comment: Your list is `fahr`, not `temperature`. The code you provided doesn’t work at all. Recheck what you posted.

Comment: The code you posted won't work in Python 2, in which `5/9` is `0`.  You might want to tag it as Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Python 2 and Python 3.
Be sure to use float types to prevent unneeded roundings (5.0/9.0)

```
def fahr2cels(fahr):
    return (fahr - 32) * 5.0/9.0

def cels2fahr(cels):
    return (cels * 9.0/5.0) + 32

temperatures = [62, 67, 73, 83, 87, 96, 100, 100, 97, 88, 84, 70] 
for t in temperatures: 
    print(round(fahr2cels(t), 2))
```

Result is:

```
16.67
19.44
22.78
28.33
30.56
35.56
37.78
37.78
36.11
31.11
28.89
21.11
```